# One after another call for same event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an event over a drop down menu. Now whenever this event happens I have to read table data, and alter it. I am reading table data using `$("table").each(function(){});` function and again altering it using the same code. But these both each functions are working parallel while I want them to execute one after another.
My code seems like:

```
$(document).on('change','#rank-q1',function(){
    $('#rank-q2').val('rank-asc');
    var data=$(this).val().split('-');
    var i=-1;
    var j=0;
    var k=0;
    //console.log(results);
    $("#tbody-emps tr").each(function(){
        k++;
        if($(this).find('td').length>6){
            var temp=alasql('select '+data[1]+' from '+data[0]+' where '+tableChoice[data[0]]+' = ?',[results[i][j][1]])[0];
            if(data[1]=='birthday' || data[1]=='grad'){
                results[i][j][0]=Date.parse(temp[data[1]]);
            }else{
                results[i][j][0]=temp[data[1]];
            }
            results[i][j][2]=$(this).html();
            console.log(results[i][j][2]);  ///Note here
        }else{
            if(i>=0){
                results[i].sort(function(a,b){
                    return a[0]>b[0]?-1:(a[0]<b[0]?1:0);
                });             
            }
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    });
    results[i].sort(function(a,b){
        return a[0]>b[0]?-1:(a[0]<b[0]?1:0);
    });
    
    console.log(results);

    var i=-1,j=0;
    $("#tbody-emps tr").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td').length>6){
            $(this).html(results[i][j][2]);
            j++;
        }else{
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    });
    console.log(results);
});
```

Since `$('table').each(function(){});` is being used two times it is executed at the same time. What should i do?
FYI: All `console.log(results)` are giving me same old value of results array while, when i am using `console.log(results[i][j][2])` it is showing me updated information. That's why it seems like those `each()` functions are running at the same time, without updating.

Comment: They will execute one after other.

Comment: They can't work in parallel, javascript is single threaded Show us more of the code as per [mcve] and provide a properly detailed problem statement as well as a real explanation of what you are trying to do with this code. See [ask]

Comment: Hard to evaluate this mentally without being able to debug in dev tools. A demo in jsfiddle, codepen, plunker or other sandbox would help

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
$('table').each(function(){
    //Some data capture and alter data
}).each(function(){
    //Modification in table data.
});
```

Comment: This won't change execution sequence of the `each` instances vs OP code, all it effectively does is make one less dom search for the tables collection